# How to check one Module Version Compability with other Module

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli-v6

I have SPA Angular Application with angular-cli@1.7.4.Now I want to upgrade application package.json dependencies and devDependencies with angular-cli@.6.0.8.
But how to know other Module like "css-loader", "@types/jasmine", "typescript","jquery" etc. etc. which all module versions need to upgrade.
Or if I change the version of one module then another module compatibility is matching or not.

Comment: Use code operator to add code.

Comment: Ok, you mean directly we can update package dependencies with latest or minor or major. It will not raise any issue/error because of dependencies... Am I right?